# to retrieve values from dropdown to textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

here am trying to change the value of text box based on the user selecting the value from the drop down, but the value selected in dropdown is not getting updated on textbox.. please help me.

here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function() {                                       
        $("#name").live("change", function() {
          $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        })
     });                                     
</script>

<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">India</option> 
<option value="Frank">Us</option> 
<option value="Jim">China</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: I think you missed the textbox in your markup

Comment: @ Tranq ... no, imissed to paste it here ...

Answer (score 1):

**To retrive selected value :**

```
$("#name").change(function() {
      $("#firstname").val($(this).val());
});
```

**To retrive selected text :**

```
$("#name").change(function() {
      $("#firstname").val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works on mine..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function() {                                       
        $("#name").live("change", function() {
          $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        });
     });                                     
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">India</option> 
<option value="Frank">Us</option> 
<option value="Jim">China</option> 
</select><br />
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thnks:) bt same code s nt wrkin on mine... ok.. I might hv missed out somthin..:( il check...

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is used to Get the current element(dom) value. [See more](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

`.attr()` is used to Get the value of an attribute of element(dom). [See More](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#name").on("change", function() {
      $("#firstname").attr('value',$(this).val());
});
```

Change `.live` to `.on` because .live is deprecated.

Comment: You can just use `this.value`.

Comment: @Blender ohh sorry i didn't understand your comment i have edited answer...+1 for u

Comment: @ blender and Dipesh.. thnx il try dis:)

Comment: its showing me like "object expected" @ line no.3, i.e document.ready, wt shd i do??..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#firstname").val($('select[name="name"]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of live use change function :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#button").click(function() {
           $("#firstname").val($("#name").val());
       });
    });                                     
</script>

<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>

<select id="name" name="name"> 
   <option value="">Please select...</option> 
   <option value="Elvis">India</option> 
   <option value="Frank">Us</option> 
   <option value="Jim">China</option> 
</select>

<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="button" />
```

this will set selected value in textbox. tested code.

Comment: thanx Devang:) bt it didn wrk:(

Comment: or Devang il paste another code which is very similar to dis, will u jus check n tel me wer its goin wrong???????????

Comment: @shona , now check my updated code , and you also check your jquery file again.

Comment: hey i want a button over here, wen user selects the text from dropdown and on click of the button i want det selected text to be updated in textbox... so pls tel wt al changes i need to make here

Comment: @shona in jquery it must be $("#importLocations").css('display','inline');

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a textbox, and you shouldn't use `live()`. (It's apparently missing in newer versions of jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/javascripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
     $(document).ready(function() {                                       
        $("#name").on("change", function() {
          $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        })
     });                                     
</script>
<input id=firstname type=text>
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="Elvis">India</option> 
<option value="Frank">Us</option> 
<option value="Jim">China</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: no, i missed to paste it ova here... <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="" readonly="readonly">

Comment: @shona: OK, there's not much difference except that it's readonly. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code except missing semi-colon inside ready function

```
  $(document).ready(function() {                                       
        $("#name").live("change", function() {
          $("#firstname").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
        });
     });
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="name" name="name"> 
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<option value="India">India</option> 
<option value="Us">Us</option> 
<option value="China">China</option>
```

enter same value both place

i thing this is the thing u want

pls check here

```
http://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/wnyKq/
```